# Wordpress - Make Google Fonts Array prior to final Output of Shortcode

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to load custom Google Fonts with the shortcode, I have a [gfont gfont=""]Text[/gfont], so basically here is what I am doing...

```
function gfont_function($arr, $content = null ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'gfont' => ''
    ), $arr));

    if(isset($arr['google_font'])) {
        if($arr['google_font'] != "") {
            $font_family = 'font-family:'.$arr['google_font'].', Helvetica, Verdana;';
            $gfont = str_replace(' ', '+', $arr['google_font']);
            wp_register_style('GoogleFonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family='.$gfont.''); 
            wp_enqueue_style('GoogleFonts');
        }
    }
    $data = '<div style="'.$font_family.'">
                    '.$content.'
            </div>';

    return $data;
 }
 add_shortcode('gfont', 'gfont_function');
```

the above code works fine for only 1 specific font that I use, I mean the shortcode will only work as its registering the style for once..

Now my question is:
I was to check how many times this shortcode [gfont] has been used on the page before the output, so instead of using multipe urls to fetch Google Fonts, I want to make an array of all used Google Fonts and use only 1 url, something like this:

wp_register_style('GoogleFonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family='.ARRAY_OF_GOOGLE_FONTS.''); //formatted properly

.. so basically I will keep a global variable (most probably) where it will add all Google Fonts used on page and then make one simple formatted url to load all of them all together. Please advise.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The shortcode you've defined is odd...However, if you must do it this way, you can wrap the enqueues in [`wp_style_is()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_style_is):

```
// If the font hasn't already been enqueued, enqueue it
if ( ! wp_style_is( 'GoogleFonts', 'enqueued' ) ) {
    wp_register_style('GoogleFonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family='.$gfont.''); 
    wp_enqueue_style('GoogleFonts');
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. where it says "gfont" in $arr its basically "google_font" it was part of larger shortcode so I just cust the part and forgot to change gfont to "google_font".. but the question is if I use this shortcode 4 times, its only going to register_style once, not for 4 different Fonts I used on different locations of my page. How can I access the shortcode before output so I can modify and make array of all fonts and then register_style...